# How to enable 3D Acceleration for Nvidia GeForce GTS 250?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I'm a Linux newbie and I need help please

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10, and I want to enable 3D acceleration

In my system info it says the graphics card is GeForce GTS 250/PCI/SSE2

Please if you can help me give me details on how to do it... thanks

Comment: lspci | grep 'VGA compatible controller:' [provide the output]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install a graphics or wireless card driver?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-a-graphics-or-wireless-card-driver)

Answer (score 2):

You can install the proprietary nvidia driver to enable 3D acceleration.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `jockey` than press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Choose the driver and click on "Activate".

[image]

Alternatively, you can also go to your system setting and click on "Adittional Drivers".

Answer (score 1):

You have to choices. You can install the driver Ubuntu picks out for you using the method above through system settings. Or you can install the restricted drivers from Nvidia via Terminal Window. This way is pretty easy it only takes a few commands and a quick restart and you will be able to run Unity in 3D. [Install Nvidia Drivers Ubuntu](http://ubuntuforum.webs.com/proprietarydrivers.htm)